# Calling the Response from Facebook Marketing API in Conditional Statements (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I'm new to Python (using 3.7, no particular reason) and setting up some automated reporting for my company. I've tried several different ways of using the response from the Marketing API. This is my starting point:

```
def account_name():
#Don't worry, I have all of my credentials as global variables, as I'm setting this up on several accounts.
daily_budget = 200

ad_account_id = 'act_xxxxxxxxxxx'

response = (AdAccount(ad_account_id).get_insights(
    fields=fields,
    params=params,
))

spend = (AdAccount(ad_account_id).get_insights(
    fields=fields2
))

print(response)
```

The response I get is:

```
[<AdsInsights> {
    "action_values": [
        {
            "action_type": "omni_add_to_cart",
            "value": "10489.9"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_purchase",
            "value": "8283.81"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "action_type": "omni_add_to_cart",
            "value": "1416"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "omni_purchase",
            "value": "288"
        }
    ],
    "clicks": "1907",
    "cpc": "0.477787",
    "cpm": "2.984927",
    "ctr": "0.62474",
    "date_start": "2020-12-14",
    "date_stop": "2020-12-14",
    "impressions": "305247",
    "purchase_roas": [
        {
            "action_type": "omni_purchase",
            "value": "9.091698"
        }
    ],
    "reach": "242920",
    "spend": "911.14"
}]
```

The problem I'm having, is that I need to pull the value for "spend" out of the response, with a conditional to make it trigger a webhook if the amount is too high. Everything I've tried either doesn't work with the data type of the response, or gives me the error "'Cursor' object is not callable". An example of what I'm looking for is something to the effect of:

```
if 'spend' > daily_budget:
     print("too high")
```

And yes, I know the above snippet is not formatted, and will not work, but that's the idea I'm looking for - just don't know how to make it happen. I'm incredibly new to Python, so I'm really stuck here. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
metrics = (AdAccount(ad_account_id).get_insights(
        fields=fields,
        params=params,
    ))
    for i in metrics:
        metrics_data = dict(i)
data = {
        "Date:": metrics_data.get("date_start"),
        "Spend:": metrics_data.get("spend"),
        "Reach:": metrics_data.get("reach"),
        "Impressions:": metrics_data.get("impressions"),
        "Clicks:": metrics_data.get("clicks"),
        "CPC:": metrics_data.get("cpc"),
        "CTR:": metrics_data.get("ctr"),
        "CPM:": metrics_data.get("cpm"),
        "ROAS:": metrics_data.get("purchase_roas")
    }
```

Then I can call the "spend" field specifically.